# joomla 2.5 acl front end edited w/o permission

Tags: joomla, permissions, joomla2.5, acl, frontend

Joomla 2.5 is being accessed from the front end and some modules/articles edited or deleted. No log in is being shown in the user manager either apart from mine. trying to figure out how, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Need More  informational to help.  Are there any custom or third party extensions being used.   What kinds of edits are being made? So forth...

Comment: Have you ensured you're running the latest version of Joomla and all your extensions?

Comment: More information needed for sure... Though are you sure the modules are edited or deleted and what you see is not just because of the configuration ? What kind of edits ? Are you sure there is not someone in the backend or your website is being compromised ? As said also ensure you have the latest joomla installed.

Comment: It is Joomla 2.5.9. The Plugins are able to be edited and i think the articles as well. There are many extentions not sure if can be entered  thru template, which is ja nex? Developers Tools console section showing this;

Comment: ailed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined (index):3
Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined (index):18
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT